# Cancel "Prepare for shipping to end user"

Tags: oem

Good evening,

i got a machine with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
The installation from Ubuntu was made as OEM.
Now the user pressed "prepare for shipping to end user".

Is there any way, to cancel this mode?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why exactly do you want to cancel it? What's the problem? But no, it isn't supposed to be cancelled anyway.

Comment: After OEM reset, System don't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

> After OEM reset the system doesn't work anymore.

The OEM reset specifications are determined by the original equipment manufacturer, so there is no easy way of knowing exactly what happens when the user selects the OEM reset option unless the manufacturer published them. The safest way to regain control of the computer after pressing the OEM reset option is to erase the existing operating system and reinstall Ubuntu as shown in this screenshot of the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer.

If you mistakenly selected the OEM option in the Ubuntu installer and you have a single boot of only Ubuntu, the easiest way to recover from it is to exit from the Ubuntu installer, reboot the Ubuntu installation media, and restart the Ubuntu installation from scratch.

[image]